# JQuery не работает когда он во внешнем файле

Tags: jquery, javascript

Проблема такая: Когда я пишу:

```
<img onclick="$(this).hide(1000);" src="img.jpg" id="image" />
```

Работает!

А когда он во внешнем файле(myjs.js):

```
$('#image').click(function() {
$('#image').hide(1000);
});
```

Связываю так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>(jQuery lib)
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>(мой)
```

Не реагирует никак!

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы уверены, что код исполняется после загрузки `DOM`? Или вы подключили скрипт в `<head/>`, не думая, когда, что и как исполняется?

Попробуйте заменить код на этот:

```
$(function(){
   $('#image').click(function(){
      $('#image').hide(1000);
   });
})
```

Comment: Аа, все! Понял как jQuery работает!)) Спасибо! Подключил их под конец, перед </body> и сработало! Спасибо!)

Comment: @navi1893, так работает не только `jQuery`, а и весь `javascript`. Поставить в конце `<body>` — один с вариантов, но можно сделать, как писал я — просто выполнять код после загрузки `DOM`-дерева, тоесть при событии `$(document).ready()`, которое можно записать короче (код выше).

Comment: я бы еще дополнил тем, что лучше не вешать в OnClick а дать картинке id или class и в вашем скрипте уже навесить нужную функцию (опять таки после загрузки документа).